# updating a photo google contacts api

Tags: api, google-contacts-api

I am trying to update a photo of a google contact with Google Contacts API.
I tried using axios (node library for making HTTP requests) to get the bytes of an image from a URL, then update the photo, sending the first image using the following URL: 
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/default/CONTACT_ID
as it is written in
[Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#addingupdating_a_photo_for_a_contact)

here is a code example:

```
`axios.post('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token', querystring.stringify(formData), {
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
}).then(function(response) {
    axios.get('http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Facebook-Download-PNG.png')
    .then(res => {
        axios.put('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/default/66b5930a931571', res.data, {
            headers: {
                // 'If-non-match': 'S0wCTlpIIip7ImA0X0QI',
                'Content-Type': res.headers['content-type'],
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + response.data.access_token,
                'GData-Version': '3.0'
            }
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        }).catch(res => {
            console.log(res.response.data) // invalid image file error 400
        })
    })`
```

The first post request is to get the code for the token and the put request is for changing the photo.
I get an 400 status code with 'invalid image file' error.

I tried to make something in python too but I get the response from the gdata library of:
gdata.client.RequestError
RequestError: Server responded with: 404, Photo not found

Comment: There is a sample python code in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#addingupdating_a_photo_for_a_contact). I think you need to try it first.

Comment: I tried the Python in the docs as I mentioned in the end of the question, but thanks